# Import Error in python when non root user

Tags: python, linux, centos, rhel, arelle

I am having an issue which has been driving me crazy.  I am trying to run a python script as a non root user but when I try to execute the script I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/EdgarRenderer/src/EdgarRenderer.py", line 13, in <module>
from arelle import PythonUtil  # define 2.x or 3.x string types
ImportError: cannot import name PythonUtil
```

Now if I execute it as the root user it runs with out a hitch.  I have triple checked all permissions and all the scripts and folders access by the desired user are in fact owned by that user (with the exception of the /usr/bin/python3.3 file).  This is the command I am trying to execute

```
su - tomcat -c '/usr/bin/python3.3 /usr/local/lib/EdgarRenderer/src/EdgarRenderer.py -c /usr/local/lib/EdgarRenderer/conf/RunEdgar.xml --xdgConfigHome=/usr/local/lib/re3/arelle'
```

I run the exact same script the exact same way on another server with out any errors.  I am using CentOS 6.5

Thanks!

Comment: -rwxrw-r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 85636 Jun 25 19:09 /usr/local/lib/EdgarRenderer/src/EdgarRenderer.py

Comment: It is not `EdgarRenderer.py` that can't be accesses, but wherever `PythonUtil` lives. Presumably you can import it as root, and check its location.

Comment: Have you checked the PYTHONPATH environment variable to be the same?

Comment: What's the best way to check where PythonUtil is located?  Looks like it is imported from the arelle package.  I am not a python guy by any means, I use perl 98% of the time.  Thanks

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3.3 -c "import arelle; print(arelle.__file__)"`

Comment: You're awesome!  Thanks, that worked.  On the other server I must have installed python3 as the tomcat user because it is in fact owned by tomcat.  Thanks again